# How do I parse HTML using Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

I'd like to parse an HTML file extracting relevant data to use in my research. Here's a piece of the HTML:

```
<td class="color_line1" valign="center"><a class="linkpadrao" href="javascript:Direciona('5453*SERRA@TALHADA');">Serra Talhada</a></td>
<td class="color_line" valign="center" align="center">9</td>
<td class="color_line" valign="center" align="center">2,973</td>
<td class="color_line" valign="center" align="center">0,016</td>
<td class="color_line" valign="center" align="center">2,939</td>
<td class="color_line" valign="center" align="center">3,000</td>
<td class="color_line" valign="center" align="center">0,572</td>
<td class="color_line" valign="center" align="center">2,401</td>
<td class="color_line" valign="center" align="center">0,024</td>
<td class="color_line" valign="center" align="center">2,378</td>
<td class="color_line" valign="center" align="center">2,426</td>
</tr>
```

Being more specific, I'd like to get the "Serra Talhada" (as a city name), and also all of the numbers below the city name (it's the max, min and average price of gas).

I tried this so far:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

url = "http://www.anp.gov.br/preco/prc/Resumo_Por_Estado_Municipio.asp"

agent = Mechanize.new

parameters = {'selSemana' => '737*De+28%2F07%2F2013+a+03%2F08%2F2013',
  'desc_semana' => 'de+28%2F07%2F2013+a+03%2F08%2F2013',
  'cod_Semana' => '737',
  'tipo' => '1',
  'Cod_Combustivel' => 'undefined',
  'selEstado' => 'PE*PERNAMBUCO',
  'selCombustivel' => '487*Gasolina',
}

municipio = []

page = agent.post(url, parameters)

extrair = page.parser

extrair.css('.linkpadrao').each do |posto|
    # Municipios
    municipio << posto.text 
end
```

I can't figure out how to get the numbers as they have the same HTML structure.

Any thoughts?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the numbers following each posto with:

```
posto.parent.search('~ td').map &:text
```

Comment: +1 Mixing DOM methods and CSS selectors are often the most readable solution.

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to find the cells with respect to the city link, you should find their common ancestor - in this case their tr.

Using xpath, you can locate a specific cell by its text:

```
# This is the table that contains all of the city data
data_table = extrair.at_css('.table_padrao')

# This is the specific row that contains the specified city
row = data_table.xpath('//tr[td/a[@class="linkpadrao" and text()="Serra Talhada"]]')

# This is the data in the specific row
data = row.css(".color_line").map{|e| e.text }
#=> ["9", "2,973", "0,016", "2,939", "3,000", "0,572", "2,401", "0,024", "2,378", "2,426"]
```

Comment: Why take a nice bit of css and turn it into an ugly xpath expression?

Comment: @pguardiario, I thought they wanted a specific row from the table based on text, hence the need for xpath.